# How to execute a jQuery callback once when scrolling stopped

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, scroll, settimeout

So I have pinpointed the scroll event in TinyScrollbar (http://www.baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/js/jquery.tinyscrollbar.js)
and I want to execute a callback to fade out the opacity of the scrollbar.

I thought using `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout` would work and it kind of does but seems to call the function as many times as `oScrollbar.obj.css({opacity:1});` but after a delay of 1000ms as set by the timeout delay.

This causes a flickering effect.

```
oScrollbar.obj.css({opacity:1});
console.log('Scrolling');
clearTimeout(fade);

var fade = setTimeout( function() {
    console.log('Scroll Stopped');
    oScrollbar.obj.stop().fadeTo(300,0)
    }, 1000);
```

Is there a better way to execute a function only once after the event has stopped being triggered?